# php curl error simplehtmldom

Tags: php, curl

I use a php script to login into a webpage using curl that works fine. Then I load two more pages and store them into variables.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $page1);
$resources = curl_exec($ch);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $page2);
$installations = curl_exec($ch);
```

I use two function to process the data In $page1 and $page 2

```
//Function findResourcesBuildings. Requires $page1
        function findResourcesBuildings($somepage)  {
            for ($i=1; $i < 10 ; $i++) { 
            $button = $i;
            $html = new simple_html_dom();
            $html->load($somepage, true, false);
            $result_tmp = preg_match_all('!\d+!', $html->find("li[id=button".$button."] span.level",0)->plaintext, $matches);
            $level = $matches[0][0];
            $state_char = $html->find("li[id=button".$button."]",0)->getAttribute('class');
            $state_title = $html->find("li[id=button".$button."] a",0)->title;
            $state = buildState($state_char,$state_title);
            $result[]=array('lvl'=>$level,'state'=>$state);
            }
        return $result;
        }

        //Function findInstallationsBuildings. Requires $page2
        function findInstallationsBuildings($somepage)  {
            for ($i=0; $i < 7 ; $i++) { 
            $button = $i;
            $html = new simple_html_dom();
            $html->load($somepage, true, false);
            $result_tmp = preg_match_all('!\d+!', $html->find("li[id=button".$button."] span.level",0)->plaintext, $matches);
            $level = $matches[0][0];
            $state_char = $html->find("li[id=button".$button."]",0)->getAttribute('class');
            $state_title = $html->find("li[id=button".$button."] a",0)->title;
            $state = buildState($state_char,$state_title);
            $result[]=array('lvl'=>$level,'state'=>$state);
            }
        return $result;
        }

$test = findResourcesBuildings($page1) //Works
$test2 = findInstallationsBuildings($page2) //  error: Call to a member function getAttribute() on a non-object
```

or

```
$test = findInstallationsBuildings($page2) //Works
$test2 = findResourcesBuildings($page1)  //  error: Call to a member function getAttribute() on a non-object
```

The error is in this line:

```
$state_char = $html->find("li[id=button".$button."]",0)->getAttribute('class');
```

But as I stated above it fails on the second variable, no matter what order.

---

What may be happening? I'm lost here.
Thanks

Comment: `$html->find` is null at this point. Add a debug statement there

Comment: Please provide the URLs of $page1 & $page2

Comment: @thanks. Renaming $html for $html1 in the second function worked. But why? I believed the scope of $html was local (only valid inside the function). unset($html) worked too. But I'm still confused.